# Why Mockito with @MockBean is returning unexpected Pass when running JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Im trying get my head around how to create a MockBean to use in connection with Mockito. In my case I have two separate classes, one which is the @Controller in which Im trying to mock in another @SpringBootTest Junit test class.

But whenever Im running the Mockito as a Junit test case I am getting unexpected result which is *pass* when it should really return *false* ?

Am I missing some kind of configuration here?

I have attached source code for both of the classes to show you:

First is the controller class:

```
package com.springboot.test.testapplication;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public String welcome(Model map) {

    map.addAttribute("welcomeMessage", "welcome");
    map.addAttribute("message", "important message");

    return "welcome";
}


//Method I'm trying to get access to
public String return100() {
    return "100";
}

}
```

and this is the Test class:

```
package com.springboot.test.testapplication;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;

@SpringBootTest
class TestapplicationApplicationTests {

@MockBean
private TestController controller;

@Test
void contextLoads() {

    Mockito.when(controller.return100()).thenReturn("2");

}
}
```

Any tips would be much appreciated..

Comment: Which part of code should return `false`?

Comment: And, you are not testing anything in the `@Test` method. This test will pass.

Comment: I was expecting that the line where I invoke Mockito.when ... should return false....have I misunderstood something about the concept of Mocking perhaps?

Comment: They way I was expecting the code to work was that after the when-call it should return the value from return100 which is a String with the value 100 and then it should compare it with what I have expected it to be....in the thenReturn parameter.

Comment: Thats not how mocking works. You defined that if something calls the method `return100` it should return `2`. However there is nothing that interacts with the mock in your test. You need to look at a tutorial what mocking is and how it is supossed to be used.

Comment: Alright, I suspected that there is a logical error in my thinking. I will look those tutorials up. Thank you !